# How do I find out who has already reserved a resource i.e. conference room in Google Calendar?

Tags: google-workspace, google-calendar

Scenario:

A small group of employees has reserved the conference room via a Google Calendar event through Gmail. At a later date a meeting with a bunch of executives is scheduled only to find the conference room is already reserved.

How can I find out who originally reserved the room so that we can negotiate a swap?

[image: screen shot]

If I'm not mistaken a calendar is created behind the scenes when you add an asset that you can "check out" with calendar events.  Is there an easy way to hook directly into that calendar?

The image below shows an asset "added to an event," which makes it a guest.  If I hover over that guest I can see there appears to be a calendar URL.  Unfortunately I don't see any way to copy that or otherwise get to the calendar without writing it down by hand and then manually typing it into Google Calendar to search.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a GApps user and calendar for each resource in your domain, and you can view it to see who booked the resource and for what duration.

1. In your [calendar](https://calendar.google.com), click the little arrow box next to "Other Calendars" and select "Browse Interesting Calendars". Who knows what you will find in here!
   [image: here be dragons]
2. Click on the "More" heading and then the blue carat (">") to expand the Resources for your domain.

[image: is a blue carat a GMO-free food?]

3. Click the "Subscribe" button next to any (all?) of the Resources that you want to view.

[image: what kind of beer does the world's most interesting calendar drink?]

4. The calendar will be displayed under "Other Calendars" on your Google Calendar page. You can then toggle the visibility as if it were a typical user's calendar.

Answer (score 2):

If you're only looking to see a single event, you can click on "Find a time" once you've added the room to your calendar invite. This will show the calendar's schedule, let you view its events and see who created another event (as long as this event isn't marked 'private')

Answer (score 0):

It seems like resources (such as meeting rooms) are handled as co-workers, and have their own calendars.

So, in the textbox in the leftmost column where you normally add co-workers' calendars, type the name of the resource and add it to your calendar setup like it were a co-worker. By clicking its calendar events, you'll be able to view their respective details (like who booked a meeting room).